# Background image not displaying in chrome browser

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I've created a small search widget, however the background doesn't appear when viewing it through chrome. I've tested IE, FF and safari which all appear OK.

http://paradigmsearch.co.uk/widget/?id=1

I'm usually reluctant to put layout issue on SO. However, I've been going over this for a while.

On the element:

```
<div class="widget" id="id_300x250">
```

I'm applying the following CSS definitions

```
.widget {
  font-family: arial;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  background: url('/uploads/widget_background/cached/proportional/300x250/1_512648b566578.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

The background just isn't visible. If this is a really silly mark-up / css oversight then I apologies profusely.

Currently using chrome browser Version 25.0.1364.172m

Comment: I see it fine, same version of Chrome, windows machine.

Comment: I can see the background just fine. I'm in chrome 25.0.1364.172 m too. And as far as I can tell, your code is fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a pretty funny issue which I only figured out when opening your page in Chrome's incognito mode: Your background image is being blocked by AdBlock.

Also, for rendering purposes it's better practice to stick `style` elements in your page's `head`.

Comment: Ah shoot! yes, I have ad block, but not for much longer. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about why it's being detected as an advert. Images on your website load fine otherwise, so you may want to move it into a different folder. :-)

Comment: Yes, it's to do with the ID name being used. 300x250 is a standard advert unit dimension, i'd do well to NOT use it. Thanks.

Comment: And not to use it as part of the image URL!

Comment: thank god for this answer, it would have been very difficult to figure this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code using chrome 25.0.1364.172m, all appear OK.
Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/rcHMc/

HTML

```
<div class="widget" id="id_300x250">
```

CSS

```
.widget {
  font-family: arial;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  background: url('http://paradigmsearch.co.uk/uploads/widget_background/cached/proportional/300x250/1_512648b566578.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```