# recaptcha show blank space in bootstrap 3 bottom page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I work with bootstrap 3 login page and add recaptcha too this. now before load complete my page i see blank page in bottom for load recaptcha.

Recaptcha:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        var RecaptchaOptions = {
                            theme: 'custom',
                            custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
                        };
                    </script>
                    <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">reCAPTCHA</label>
                            <div class="controls"> <a id="recaptcha_image" href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>

                                <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="recaptcha_only_if_image control-label">Enter the words above:</label>
                            <label class="recaptcha_only_if_audio control-label">Enter the numbers you hear:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div class="input-append">
                                    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" class="input-recaptcha" /> <a class="btn" href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
 <a class="btn recaptcha_only_if_image" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')"><i title="Get an audio CAPTCHA" class="icon-headphones"></i></a>
 <a class="btn recaptcha_only_if_audio" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')"><i title="Get an image CAPTCHA" class="icon-picture"></i></a>
 <a class="btn" href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $recaptcha_url; ?>">

                    </script>
                    <noscript>
                        <iframe src="<?php echo $recaptcha_noscript_url; ?>" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        <br>
                        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
                    </noscript>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcrK9cSAAAAALEcjG9gTRPbeA0yAVsKd8sBpFpR"></script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="<?php echo $recaptcha_noscript_url; ?>" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <br>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
        </noscript>
```

how do fix this ?

DEMO (click in run and see problem) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqv27/849/)

Pic:

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/R2C3EJQ.png . Are you using some kind of blocking addon?

Comment: I think in the moment of the reload the bottom part is blank and that's not the way he wants it

Comment: well i don't see any blank space while loading either

Comment: @JohnSmith: after load i too see complete page without blank page!! when page is loading for load recaptcha i see blank page.

Comment: @JohnSmith: it's like a split second for me when it's blank.

Comment: I see no issues in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: This may be a similar issue to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550560/background-image-not-displaying-in-chrome-browser. Do you have any ad blocking plugins enabled on your browser?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: no i not have. i checked this in FF, Chrome, ie and not work in browsers.

Comment: @j08691: u refresh result?? in refresh when recaptcha need to load image blank space is show. this demo is without design: http://jsfiddle.net/hqv27/ in refresh/run u see div is resize and then show image.

Comment: Every time I reload the page or refresh the captcha is runs fine here in Chrome.

Comment: the fiddle looks fine to me, in latest chrome and ff...

Comment: @j08691: in full screen result u see full gray background?! http://jsfiddle.net/hqv27/849/embedded/result/

Comment: I see gray all the way down to the sign me in button.

Comment: I think this is my problem!!! gray backgroud should be full background in body not down to the sign..

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't acquire and add your [RECAPTCHA API Key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#createsite).