# CSS-defined background image doesn't display in Chrome

Tags: css, background-image

I know there's a ton of similar questions about this on here, but none seem to address the issue for me.

css code:

```
/*Deferred Payment Popup*/
div.DeferredPaymentPopup {
}

div.DeferredPaymentPopup input.RefreshImage {
    background-image: url(../Images/Refresh-icon.png);
    background-position: left top;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

Code on page -

```
<div id="DeferredPaymentPopup" class="DeferredPaymentPopup newportal popup" title="Deferred Payment Calculator">
<div data-bind="with: statement.viewModel.DeferredPaymentModel">
...
  <div id="divDollarCalc">
    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 4px">
    <input type="image" onclick="return false;" title="Refresh" class="RefreshImage" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

There's a number of nested divs on the page, and a couple of them have their own IDs - I included one of them for illustration.

No issues in IE or Edge.

All looks well on inspect in Chrome:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15550900/7427111, check if this is not the issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but based on the HTML you've included in your question, the input with class attribute "RefreshImage" is not a child of the div with class "DeferredPaymentPopup", which is how your CSS rule is targeting it.

Comment: @OliverTooEh - I didn't want to include ALL the code in between the tags (hence the ellipses) but it is indeed within the initial div. I edited the indents in the snippet to make that more clear. As I mentioned, it's behaving in the other browsers.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh - I saw that question, and I did check that. I don't have AdBlock running on this machine, but I turned off Chrome's internal ad blocking, to no avail.  Also, that one looked more like the graphic was a standard ad size, which added to the confusion. This is happening on all users' machines, not just mine.

Comment: try replacing the file path with any url online. And check if you are facing the same problem. For Convenience, replace it with this URL : https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg

Comment: It does not display.  Adding a src attrib to the input tag and assigning it to a random graphic DOES work, as suggested below, but I'm curious why that would be needed for this one example, and not others in the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `src` attribute of `input[type=image]`

```
<input type="image" src="../Images/Refresh-icon.png" />
```

**Clarification for the questions from comments:**

For `input[type=image]` and `img` tags in chrome, if there is no `src` attribute or invalid `src` attribute, browser shows the icon of broken image which is not background, that's why you cant override it from css background.

However `img` tag is not showing the icon when there is no `src` attribute at all, it is showing only when the value of `src` is invalid.

But for `input[type=image]` it is showing up even when there is no `src` attribute, this behavior is different for `img` and `input[type=image]`.

I don't know the exact reason behind that, but my guess is that may be `src` is optional for `img` but not for `input[type=image]`.

As per the problem `input[type=submit]` not working, if you can provide the new code you have tried we should be able to help you with that.

This is a small experiment that shows how it works

```html
<p><strong>input type="image"</strong></p>

<p>Without src</p>
<input type="image" style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;"/>

<p>With src</p>
<input type="image" style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/e91a3dcf-c15a-441a-b369-996922364cdc-profile_image-300x300.png"/>

<br />
<br />
<p><strong>input type="submit"</strong></p>
<p>With background</p>
<input type="submit" style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;"/>

<br />
<br />
<p><strong>img</strong></p>

<p>Without src</p>
<img style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;"/>

<p>With empty src</p>
<img style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;" src />

<p>With invalid src</p>
<img style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;" src="//avcs" />

<p>With valid src</p>
<img style="display:inline-block;width:  40px;height: 40px;background: #000;" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/e91a3dcf-c15a-441a-b369-996922364cdc-profile_image-300x300.png" />
```

Comment: I can indeed, and that does clear the issue, but I'm curious why it'd be needed?  Is there some base difference with how Chrome handles background images that the src is required?  There are other cases where css-defined background images are working fine.  The only difference I see is that as I mentioned, this one is within a number of nested divs. named and un-named.

Comment: It is explained in the linked issue, you can check that

Comment: I did - the question talks about a border around a graphic, which isn't the issue being discussed The link to whatwg.org talks about the src attrib being required, but that entry doesn't seem to be discussing a tag using css.  And as I said, I have other images with no src attrib that work just fine.

Comment: For the record, changing the tag to a submit type, the other thing suggested in that question, does not fix the problem.

Comment: I'm going to declare this the answer as it solves the problem, but damned if I can figure out why it's needed, and only needed in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use .DeferredPaymentPopup, input.RefreshImage{...} because RefreshImage is not a child of the DeferredPaymentPopup div

---

**Edit**
Is this what you intend to achieve? Instead of input `type="image"` , I used text

```css
div.DeferredPaymentPopup {}

div.DeferredPaymentPopup input.RefreshImage {
  background: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1526907328/483257_vwhhfw.jpg") no-repeat left top;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="DeferredPaymentPopup" class="DeferredPaymentPopup newportal popup" title="Deferred Payment Calculator">
  <div data-bind="with: statement.viewModel.DeferredPaymentModel">
    
    <div id="divDollarCalc">
      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 4px">
        <input type="text" onclick="return false;" title="Refresh" class="RefreshImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use `.DeferredPaymentPopup, input.RefreshImage{...}` because `RefreshImage` is not a child of the `DeferredPaymentPopup` div

Comment: He didn't post the entire HTML code, but from chrome inspect it is clear that the rule is being applied to the input.

Comment: As mentioned above, I edited the indents to make it more clear that it is indeed inside the base div.

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola Yes and no - the image shows up, but then I get the image border problem that's mentioned in the question below, and adding the src attribute doesn't fix it. Simply adding the src attrib and leaving it an image is the best solution so far, but I'm still curious WHY it's needed. I suspect I'll have to chalk it up to "it just is"

Comment: luckily for us, @AvcS saved the day :)